# How can I target just numbers in a RegEx redirect condition?

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I recently changed all of my Wordpress blog URLs to NOT include the year, month and date.

Rather than create individual redirect rules, I'd like to use RegEx to create just one wildcard rule.

So to go from URLs like `http://www.example.com/blog/2015/01/01/blog-title/` to `http://www.example.com/blog/blog-title/`.

I need to be able to recognise that numbers are being entered after /blog/ for it not to interfere with other URLs I have.

So I tried to enter this rule in my redirection plugin:

Source URL: `/blog/^[0-9]*$/^[0-9]*$/^[0-9]*$/(.*)`
Target URL: `/blog/$1/`

But this doesn't seem to redirect at all, so the source isn't being recognised. What rule should I be using to find any digit after the /blog/ in the yyyy/mm/dd format?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `/`, and the `$` is matching from the end of the string. So you need something like

```
blog\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(.*)
```

This should do the replacement (generated by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oK0vK1/1)):

```
$re = "/blog\\/\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/(.*)/"; 
$str = "http://www.example.com/blog/2015/01/01/blog-title"; 
$subst = "blog/$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/blog-title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond ^/blog/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```